# "MATLABWindow application failed to launch..." Why isn't MATLAB functioning properly?

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu-18.04

Hello StackOverFlow world! I am a novice to computer programming and would appreciate your guidance solving this issue I am confronting in MATLAB. I've been experimenting with MATLAB by using theSimulink function, however, I was hit with a notification saying:

```
   Warning: MATLABWindow application failed to launch. Unable to launch the MATLABWindow application
   >In sltemplate.ui.StartPage/showWithFallback
    In sltemplate.ui.StartPage.show
```

I searched on several forums online and they advised me to enter the following the commands to further analyze the situation.

```
  >> cd(matlabroot)
    >> ! bin/glnxa64/MATLABWindow
    bin/glnxa64/MATLABWindow: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard
```

I've been searching far and wide for my specific issue but I've yet to have found a solution. Looking forward to your responses!

Comment: Have you followed their own troubleshooting? https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/364551-why-is-matlab-unable-to-run-the-matlabwindow-application-on-linux

Comment: I actually referred to that troubleshooting guide but my specific issue is not covered.

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/388052-why-is-my-matlab-unable-to-run-simulink-matlabwindow It is linked int he post definetly. Its exactly the same error

Comment: I'm confused, I see the guide handles this issue but I'm thrown off due to the OP of that post using Arch Linux while I'm using Linux ubuntu 18.04 . Will the same steps of that guide work for Linux Ubuntu?

Comment: You should contact mathworks about this.

Comment: I run into the same error (also using Ubuntu 18.04 and MATLAB 2018a). I tried excluding `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0` as described in the solution MathWorks proposed, but then MATLAB doesn't start at all. Also, I don't have the `libatk` library in the MATLAB directory.

Answer (score 4):

[Reference](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/409319-libatk-1-0-so-0-error-in-ubuntu-bionic-18-04-or-linux-mint-tara-19-using-matlab-r2018a#answer_337182)

1. Go to matlab root folder
2. cd /cefclient/sys/os/glnxa64/
3. mkdir bak
4. mv * bak
5. mv bak/libcef.so ./

Tested under ubuntu 18.04 with matlab r2017a

Comment: Since it may vary which library is the problem, run MATLABWindow directly to find out if it's libcef or something else. https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/540707-why-does-matlab-fail-to-install-with-a-std-runtime_error-what-unable-to-launch-the-matlabwind#answer_770839